# Ember Controller method to manipulate parameters and return a value to the view?

Tags: ember.js

```
{{#each accounts as |account|}}
<li title={{someMethodReturnsValue(account)}}>{{account.accName}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Helpers can be used but just trying to find a solution within controller itself. Is there any way ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Handlebars doesn’t really permit function calls in that sense, it would be more idiomatic to create a derived property in the controller that you iterate through.

Template:

```
{{#each accountsWithTitles as |account|}}
  <li title={{account.title}}>{{account.accName}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Controller:

```
accountsWithTitles: computed('accounts.[]', function() {
  return this.accounts.map(account => {
    return {
      ...account,
      title: someMethodReturnsValue(account),
    };
  });
})
```

That computed property is speculative of course, but gives the general idea.

Comment: A template helper might be another solution to the problem. Highly depends on what `someMethodReturnsValue` should do.

Comment: Thankyou Doyle, This is absolutely another way to get a return value. This adds a property to the object whereas helpers just return a value without adding a new property !